# No response in trying to retrieve the profile pictures with facebook api

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, curl

I'm actually trying to get user's profile picture with facebook graph but.
When i make mistakes in query i get response error but when query looks good, I get nothing.

looks good  but nothing :

> curl
>   https://graph.facebook.com/FACEBOOK_USER_ID/picture\?access_token\=GOOD_ACCESS_TOKEN

response : nothing.

wrong access token :

> curl
>   https://graph.facebook.com/FACEBOOK_USER_ID/picture\?access_token\=WRONG_ACCESS_TOKEN

response :

```
{"error":{"message":"The access token could not be decrypted","type":"OAuthException","code":190,"fbtrace_id":"AfwXN3diqN5"}
```

wrong facebook user id :

> curl
>   https://graph.facebook.com/WRONG_FACEBOOK_USER_ID/picture\?access_token\=GOOD_ACCESS_TOKEN

response :

```
{"error":{"message":"(#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: 12955422413187","type":"OAuthException","code":803,"fbtrace_id":"Dolxmgphza"}}
```

looks good with parametersbut nothing :

> curl
>   https://graph.facebook.com/FACEBOOK_USER_ID/picture\?access_token\=GOOD_ACCESS_TOKEN&type=large

response : nothing.

Have you an idea?

Thanks :)

Comment: You don't need access token to get public profile picture.

Comment: @RuiCosta yes but i get the same result if i don't use access token

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URLs of the form `https://graph.facebook.com/FACEBOOK_USER_ID/picture` issue a *redirect* to the actual location of the image on Facebook’s CDN (unless you explicitly request otherwise.)

So you won’t get to “see” anything (because it’s just HTTP headers), unless you tell cURL to follow redirects/Location headers - that what the [`-L`/`--location`](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-L) option is for.

Comment: Ok thank's i've found, it's not about that, it's about parameters "redirect"
which by default to true and must be set to false. anyway thank you for your help :)